# create SVG group with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I want to create Elements with `g` tagname for SVG using JavaScript.

The next code work in Google Chrome but not in Firefox, and I want this work in both.

```
svg=document.getElementsByTagName("svg").item(0)
group=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","g");
group.setAttribute("name","mygroup")
svg.appendChild(group);
```

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: I think you need to use getElementsByTagNameNS instead and provide the SVG namespace as one of the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The only "problem" that is obvious here is that an attribute called `name` has no meaning in SVG.  Did you perhaps mean `id`?

Comment: Yes, this line not work's, in chrome run. the id is useless for my porposes.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I had was with your first line:

```
svg=document.getElementsByTagName("svg").item(0)
```

I just had a quick try in some browsers (sorry, I don't have FireFox installed in a remotely sane way) and with some it didn't get the SVG, even though it was the only one on the page.  So I gave the SVG an ID and then it worked.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/9RhG2/

Comment: Try using getElementsByTagNameNS instead